# Using jQuery, how do I set the value of a hidden field and read it to confirm it was set correctly?

Tags: jquery

In the function below, the code should take a parameter,

1) display an alert with the parameter value
2) save the value to a hidden field
3) display an alert with the value read from the hidden field.

Step 1 works. I can't confirm Step 2 is occuring and Step 3 returns 'undefined'.

The first alert shows the correct ID - the ID passed to SaveReportId().

The second alert shows "SaveReportId() after save: undefined"

```
function SaveReportId(selectedReportId) {
    alert('SaveReportId() before save: ' + selectedReportId);
    $('#HiddenReportId').val(selectedReportId);
    alert('SaveReportId() after save: ' + $('#HiddenReportId').val());
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="hiddenValues">
    <input id="HiddenReportId" type="hidden" runat="server" class="HiddenReportId" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML ? cause it works here http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/Pjydr/

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: What does your input element look like? I'm guessing you have a name defined but not an id or your id has a type-o

Comment: What type of element is `#HiddenReportId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hidden field had a runat="server" attribute. I removed it and the code runs fine...

```
function SaveReportId(selectedReportId) {
    alert('SaveReportId() before save: ' + selectedReportId);
    $('#HiddenReportId').val(selectedReportId);
    alert('SaveReportId() after save: ' + $('#HiddenReportId').val());
}
```

Comment: So, the element did not exist. To get a value, **never** use `.attr('value')`, but `.val()`.

Comment: @Rob W - I changed the val() to attr() trying to get things to work. Prod code now using val() and the above is updated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no element with ID`HiddenReportId` (hence `undefined` when using `.val()`). Make sure that you're correctly spelling the ID.

jQuery won't generate errors when an element does not exist.
At the third line, nothing happens (since the element cannot be found).
At the fourth line, `.val()` returns `undefined`, because the element could not be found, thus `.value()` made no sense.

To confirm that the element does not exist, add `alert($('#HiddenReportId').length)`.

(If the element existed, `.val()` would return an empty string).